# Tricky ODE with strange B.C. NDSolve vs. DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

This is a tricky ODE. First order.
$$
y'(x)=y^2(x)-2 y(x)+1
$$

This is easily solved by hand, since separable.  But the trick is with the boundary conditions. It is $y(1)=1$.  When solving it by hand, one can argue that constant of integration is infinity as only choice, and this should lead to solution $y(x)=1$.  This what `NDSolve` gives, and also what Maple gives. But `DSolve` was not happy. It gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

First, here is the code

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y'[x] - y[x]^2 + 2 y[x] == 1;
sol = NDSolve[{ode, y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So $y(x)=1$ looks correct. Here is Maple answer as well to confirm

```
ode:=diff(y(x),x)-y(x)^2+2*y(x)=1;
sol:=dsolve({ode,y(1)=1},y(x));

         sol := y(x) = 1
```

Now here is `DSolve`

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y'[x] - y[x]^2 + 2 y[x] == 1;
sol = DSolve[ode, y[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now adding the B.C.

```
 sol = DSolve[{ode, y[1] == 1}, y[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The trick comes from the boundary conditions. Here is my hand solution, and what I had to argue at the end, in order to get the solution $y(x)=1$ to come out.

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx}  & =y^{2}-2y+1\\
y\left(  1\right)    & =1
\end{align*}

This is separable

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{y^{2}-2y+1}  & =dx\\
\frac{dy}{\left(  y-1\right)  ^{2}}  & =dx
\end{align*}

For $y\neq1$. Integrating

\begin{align}
\int\frac{dy}{\left(  y-1\right)^{2}  }  & =\int dx\nonumber\\
\frac{-1}{y-1}  & =x+C\nonumber\\
\left(  y-1\right)  \left(  x+C\right)    & =-1\nonumber\\
y  & =\frac{-1}{x+C}+1\tag{2}
\end{align}

To find $C$ using $y\left(  1\right)  =1$ gives

\begin{align*}
1  & =\frac{-1}{1+C}+1\\
1  & =\frac{C}{1+C}%
\end{align*}
The above is only possible if we set $C=\infty$. Therefore from (2), we
conclude that
$$
y(x)=1
$$

Ok, I am not a math major and do not play one on TV so may be the argument above is not 100% valid math-wise, may be I needed to take the limit there, but it is only way I could get the hand solution to match what Maple and `NDSolve` came up with. Otherwise, one can't determine the constant of integration $C$, and I think that is what `DSolve` was not happy about?

**The question is**:  Who is right?  Is `DSolve` correct by not giving $y(x)=1$ as solution?  But `NDSolve` did? How Did then Maple give the analytical solution $y(x)=1$?  Can one persuade `DSolve` somehow to give $y(x)=1$ as solution?

Version 11.0.1 on windows.

Comment: Certainly, you are correct.  `DSolve` evidently cannot handle this limiting case.  If you wish to obtain a Mathematica solution, apply `DSolve` with no boundary condition, replace `C[1]` by `1/a`, and apply the boundary condition to `Solve` for `a`, which gives the desired result, I believe.

Comment: `sol = y[x] /. DSolve[{ode, y[1] == a}, y[x], {x, 0, 1}][[1]] /. a -> 1` evaluates to `1`

Comment: Should this be tagged as a bug then? I was going to report it to WRI but was not sure if it considered a bug or not.

Comment: `DSolve` has many problems, but I would not call this a bug.